# Log of Complex number using both positive and negative angles

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I came across this question. Determine in polar form $\ln(−4−i3)$,

Using the Euler's I converted $(−4−i3)$ to:

i) $5e^{i3.79}$  using counterclockwise angle

ii) $5e^{-i2.5}$ using clockwise angle

Then performing ln gives me two different polar answers. Apparently the book uses i) for the answer. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? Every non-zero complex number has infinitely many logarithms. Your two approaches lead to distinct logarithms. That's all.

Comment: To add to this, because there are infinitely many choices we can make for the logarithm of a complex number we usually specify a principal value, i.e. that the angle should lie between $[0,2\pi[$ or $]-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: I was expecting that the first angle from the positive direction which corresponds with the first angle from the negative direction would have given the same polar form. Hope you can help me clarify.

Comment: Note that if $-3-4i=e^{\theta i}$, then, for each $k\in\mathbb Z$,$$-3-4i=e^{\theta i+2k\pi i}.$$Therefore, there are infinitely many polar forms of $-3-4i$ (or of any complex number, for that matter).